# MYSQL Error while doing partition on string column | Error Code: 1503 A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I've a product table with huge amount of data. I've already done indexing but still taking longer than expected while searching for data. Now I want to partition my table based on category column which contains string. I've total of 168 type of category in my table.
This is my query to achieve partition:

```
ALTER TABLE products  PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS  (category) ( 
PARTITION category1 VALUES IN ('Battery Trays') ,
PARTITION category2 VALUES IN ('Auto Glass') ,
PARTITION category3 VALUES IN ('Bumpers AND Parts') 
);
```

But it returns an error:

```
Error Code: 1503
A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

Here is my table structure

https://ibb.co/4jY9Tcv

Does anyone know proper method of partitioning ? why should I include PK for all columns in the table like the error says?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: I'm not an expert in partioning but the manual has this 'In MySQL 5.7, it is possible to match against only a list of integers' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-list.html and the error I get if I try to emulate is not what you get.

Comment: I'm total newbie at partitioning. I've a little knowledge about indexing but totally no practical knowledge about partitioning. 

I saw some tutorials on youtube they did exactly what I want. but when I tried, this error poped up ! :'( struggling with this since two days.

Comment: Provide the indexes, preferably as text from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning does *not* inherently provide performance.  Without seeing your `SELECT`, it is hard to give you a straight answer.  We can discuss whether an improvement (such as 'composite') will improve performance.  So, let's see the indexes, too.

When adding (or removing) partitioning, one must redesign all the `INDEXes`, since the partitioning, itself, provides (sort of) a second dimension of indexing.

See this for discussing of the 4 use cases for partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

The tutorials probably tell you what *can* be done, but not whether partitioning is *worth* doing.